# How to update binding value to default value of its type when control is disabled?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have some controls that are binded with property of search model. All input controls will be disabled when radio is not checked. I need to set binding value of search model to default value (of its type) when control is disabled without changing any value of current control.

[image]

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the IsEnable property of each TextBox with a property in your ViewModel then when it becomes false you can set the value property to its defalut value.